# "Shared with" only display local users

Tags: sharepoint-online

**Context** : I have a site (sharepoint online), which is separated into file library. Each file library have an administrator (with full control) on his library.

**Problem** : When they want to see with who they have shared somethink in the file library (right click -> share --> shared with), they can only see the local person (knon in our AD) WHEN as a site manager, I can see those external shares.
How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to SharePoint admin center->site collections tab, select the relevant site collection->click Share in the ribbon.

Check if the status is Not allowed for Allowing non-owners to invite new users. If so, it will not display external users for library owners.

[image]

To enable the feature, you can go to SharePoint site->site settings->site permissions->Access Request Settings->tick all the checkboxs in the dialog.

Comment: Not sure you'v understood well the question.
It is only about the view (they can invite external users but they cant see them ("shared with") even when the user is authentified)